running testpmd on k8s dpdk pod with nonroot privileges
I am running testpmd on non-privileged k8s pod. while i am running the below testpmd command, i am getting the error:
sh-4.2$ /usr/bin/testpmd -l 0-1 -w 0000:5e:01.3 --file-prefix p --socket-mem 1024,1024  -- -i --nb-cores=1 --coremask=0x2 --txpkts=1024 --forward-mode=txonly --port-topology=chained --rxq=1 --txq=1
ENTER dpdk-app:
 argc=18
 /usr/bin/testpmd -l 0-1 -w 0000:5e:01.3 --file-prefix p --socket-mem 1024,1024 -- -i --nb-cores=1 --coremask=0x2 --txpkts=1024 --forward-mode=txonly --port-topology=chained --rxq=1 --txq=1
EAL: Detected 32 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 2 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /tmp/dpdk/p/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: No available hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: PCI device 0000:5e:01.3 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1889 net_iavf
EAL:   using IOMMU type 1 (Type 1)
EAL:   cannot set up DMA remapping, error 12 (Cannot allocate memory)
EAL:   0000:5e:01.3 DMA remapping failed, error 12 (Cannot allocate memory)
EAL: Requested device 0000:5e:01.3 cannot be used
testpmd: No probed ethernet devices
Interactive-mode selected
nb segments per TX packets=1 >= nb_txd=0 - ignored
Set txonly packet forwarding mode
testpmd: mlockall() failed with error "Cannot allocate memory"
testpmd: create a new mbuf pool <mbuf_pool_socket_0>: n=155456, size=2176, socket=0
testpmd: preferred mempool ops selected: ring_mp_mc
testpmd: create a new mbuf pool <mbuf_pool_socket_1>: n=155456, size=2176, socket=1
testpmd: preferred mempool ops selected: ring_mp_mc
Done

Thanks for any direction in resolving this error.
